# More PWA apps on Firebase hosting, how to?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I would like to have more independent PWA apps on Firebase hosting. Each on separte subdomain, e.g.:

app1.site.com, app2.site.com, app3.site.com

I have no idea how to configure Firebase hosting and how to organize files and folders.

I have searched web but found nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase doesn't yet support hosting different web apps under the same Project. You will want to create a separate Firebase project for each of your PWAs, and connect the appropriate custom domain to each.